# How can I make a bookmarklet javascript execute in Selenium IDE?

Tags: javascript, selenium-ide

My goal is to get the javascript from a bookmarklet to execute in Selenium IDE. I know that I can add the script to my Selenium IDE test using Command: Execute Script and Target: javascript:...

I've successfully executed a simple javascript, but I can't figure out how to get the bookmarklet's js to work. I'm using Selenium IDE for Firefox on Mac OS X.

I've tried executing the javascript copied directly from the bookmarklet and rewriting the code in many different ways to debug the errors.

This is the bookmarklet's javascript directly copied from the browser. This always generates errors. 
`javascript:(function()%20%7B%0A%20%20var%20script%20=%20document.createElement('script')%0A%20%20;script.setAttribute('id',%20'ss-bookmarklet-script')%0A%20%20;script.setAttribute('data-env',%20'live')%0A%20%20;script.type%20=%20'text/javascript'%0A%20%20;script.src%20=%20'//shopstylecollective.com/iframe-script.js?t='%20+%20Date.now()%0A%20%20document.body.appendChild(script)%0A%7D)()`

This is my latest version of the script where it's generating an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` error highlighting this part at the end of the code `document.body.appendChild(script)})()`.

```
javascript:(function() {
  var script = document.createElement('script')
  ;script.setAttribute('id', 'ss-bookmarklet-script')
  ;script.setAttribute('data-env', 'live')
  ;script.type = 'text/javascript'
  ;script.src = '//shopstylecollective.com/iframe-script.js?t=' + Date.now() document.body.appendChild(script)
})()
```

The bookmarklet is supposed to open the ShopStyle Collective affiliate link creation window.

Comment: Missing a `;` before `document.body.appendC..`

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much!